# Inequalities in integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, indefinite-integrals

We are given the value of $S_n$ below and we have to find if $S_n$ is greater or smaller than $\dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$.

$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}$$

$$S_n<\dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} \quad \text{or}\quad S_n>\dfrac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

I tried it as follows:

$$S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2+\frac{k}{n}+1}$$

$$\rightarrow \frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$$

But at last I thought to draw the graph so that I can do something with area under the curve or can thought at extreme points i.e at $n$ is approaching to infinity.

I got stuck not able to do anything. You can see the image of my attempt [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk330.jpg).

Comment: I typed up your image, but kept a copy in a link. If anything is not the same let me know. In future you can use [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) guide on meta to typing up equations in questions.

Comment: @snulty thanks a lot . Can you help me in this question

Comment: What does this part mean? $$\rightarrow \frac{1}{k^2+k+1}$$ Maybe in your image you meant $$\rightarrow \frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$$ I.e. the function under the integral

Comment: Your last step, as hinted by Yuiry above, does not mean anything (there cannot be a $k$ left after the limit, nor a $n$ for that matter). You may want to have a look at "Riemann sums."

Comment: @YuriyS yes you both are correct , but help me , how to proceed

Comment: As Clement said, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html

Comment: @koolman The function $f\colon x\in[0,1]\mapsto \frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$ is decreasing (show it), $S_n$ is its Riemann sum with the lower approximation. Hence, $S_n \operatorname{?} \int_0^1 f(x)dx$. (where $?$ is either < or >)

Comment: To determine which Riemann sum you have ('left' or 'right', i.e. with greater or lower approximation), see at which point do you start ($k=1$, i.e. $x=1/n$) and at which point do you finish ($k=n$, i.e. $x=1$). So you finish at the rightmost point, but you start with some non-zero point. I think it's obvious why you have 'right' sum, i.e. lower approximation. Look at the pictures in Wikipedia article

Comment: @YuriyS but from this I am not getting the desired result

Comment: What **is** the desired result, according to you?

Comment: @ClementC. To show the above inequality

Comment: Can anybody please post a proper answer . Please

Comment: Really? You have all the pieces, try to fill in the gaps. (a) $(S_n)_n$ is a Riemann sum for $f$ converging to $\int_0^1 f = \frac{f}{3\sqrt{3}}$. (b) $f$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$. (c) $(S_n)_n$ is a "right-approximation" Riemann sum for $f$, and therefore $S_n < \int_0^1 f$ for all $n$ because of (b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Look at this picture. The red curve is the function $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$

The red curve is decreasing on $[0,1]$, since $\displaystyle f'(x)=-\frac{2x+1}{\left(x^2+x+1\right)^2}<0$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$.

The gray shaded area is the value of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2+\frac{k}{n}+1}$ when $n=6$.

Can you see why? The width of each box is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}$, and the height of the $k$th box is $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2+\frac{k}{n}+1}$.

As you can see, as $n$ increases, the number of boxes will increase, but the shaded area will never be equal to or greater than the area under the red curve for the interval $[0,1]$. (By the way, these approximations of the area under the curve are called Riemann sums.)

Ergo, we conclude that $\displaystyle S_n<\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^2+x+1}$

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^2+x+1}&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}
\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{du}{u^2+1} \qquad\text{(Substitute $u=\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}$, $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$)}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan(u)\bigg|_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{\sqrt{3}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}$$

And thus we have our desired result.

(By the way, since I am bad at calculus, I used the following sites: http://www.integral-calculator.com/, http://www.derivative-calculator.net/)

Comment: Good answer -- if you could find a way to include "Riemann sum" somewhere, that'd be even better (for the sake of indexing, and, well... because that's what it is).

Comment: Why the width of each box is 1/n

Comment: @Hrhm I took the liberty to make a few changes to the $LaTeX$ code, let me know if they look alright to you.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, that looks great! Thank you so much.

Comment: @koolman. All of the $n$ boxes have the same width, and the sum of their widths is $1$.